# Check if desired pair of values exist in a text file

Tags: ruby

I have a text file whose data look as follows:

```
var1="something1"
var2="some432543"

var1="something2"
var2="somethifdsng22dsf"

var1="some3223423"
var2="somethifdsng22dsf"

var1="somet76598764322==-"
var2="som@fds2002)02-"

# and so on....
```

That is, I have a list of pairs of `var1` and `var2`. I want to find if a pair with a certain value of `var1`/`var2` exists. I can do this for `var1` like this:

```
  value1 = "somet76598764322==-"
  value2 = "som@fds2002)02-"

  f1 = File.readlines("my_file.txt")

  # find var1
  exists = f1.grep(/var1=\"#{value1}\"/).size > 0

  if exists 
     # what about var2???
  end
```

But this is a half of what I need. What will be a decent way to check both `var1` and `var2`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  # the second value is the only one that needs to be escaped,
  # but doing it to both doesn't hurt
  var1= Regexp.escape "somet76598764322==-"
  var2= Regexp.escape "som@fds2002)02-"

  # use read not readlines since you want to match across multiple lines
  f1 = File.read("my_file.txt")

  # add a \n and the second var to the regex
  exists = x.scan(/var1=\"#{var1}\"\nvar2=\"#{var2}\"/).empty?
```

Comment: `\n` will efficiently discard files created on Win platforms.

Comment: @mudasobwa, what should be used then?

Answer (score 0):

```
value1, value2 = ['var1="somet76598764322==-"', 'var2="som@fds2002)02-"']
File.readlines('my_file.txt')
    .each_slice(3)
    .map { |arr| arr.map(&:strip) }
    .detect do |var1, var2, _|
  [var1, var2] == [value1, value2]
end
#⇒ [
#   [0] "var1=\"somet76598764322==-\"",
#   [1] "var2=\"som@fds2002)02-\""
# ]
```

This is more efficient than `grep` since it walks through the input only once and stops immediately after finding the match.